# How to get Index of the FORM Element in the WebBrowser Control?

Tags: vb.net, browser, webbrowser-control

let say a site has 2 forms: one **search form** and the other is a **registration form**...

```
<form>
Search: <input type="text" name="s">
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="search">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

[..]website content blabla[...]

<h2>Registration</h2>
<form>
E-Mail: <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="reg">
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

If I submit a form, **I want to know to which form the clicked submit button belongs.** GetElementbyId is not possible because the id is not always available. I want to get the index. Any ideas? (WebBrowser Element in VB.NET or C#)

Answer (score 1):

You cant refer to Form object of Input Element e.g `btn.Form.Name` should work; give it a try

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703812(v=vs.85).aspx (reference to IHTMLInputElement::form Property)

Comment: it works if the form has a name, but as in my example there is only a <form> tag with no attributes.

Comment: In that case you can identify form by action attribute ?

Comment: or check what is the name of first element in `btn.Form.elements[0]` if its is "s" it is searchform elseif "email" .... you know